# Passing apply the arguments array-like object returns wrong value

Tags: javascript

Documentation says this:

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).
>
> thisArg
>
> The value of this provided for the call to fun.
>
> argsArray
>
> An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which fun should be called, or null or undefined if no arguments should beprovided to the function.

Ok so this is my test:

```
function A(age){
  this.age=age;
}
A.prototype.random_age = Math.random();
function B(name,age){
  A.apply(this, arguments);
  this.name=name
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B("John",25); 
console.log("age: " + b.age + " name: " + b.name + " random age " + b.random_age);
```

Unexpectedly, I get the following:

```
age: John name: John random age 0.9844443484632327
```

Age should be 25 not "John". I passed this (which is the object created by the A function). And I want to copy B's properties into this. And the values in those properties are defined in arguments array-like object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A(age)`

Has one parameter. `arguments` is an object with two elements in your case. When you just pass `arguments` object you essentially pass the element with index 0, which in your case is name. If you reverse the arguments you will have what you want

```
function A(age){
  this.age=age;
}
A.prototype.random_age = Math.random();
function B(age, name){
  A.apply(this, arguments);
  this.name=name;
  console.log(arguments)
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B(25, "John"); 
console.log("age: " + b.age + " name: " + b.name + " random age " + b.random_age);
```

But what you really should do is to manipulate the data in a way that suits your needs.

```
function A(age){
  this.age=age;
}
A.prototype.random_age = Math.random();
function B(name, age){
  A.apply(this, [arguments[1]]); // or even better A.apply(this, [age]);
  this.name=name;
  console.log(arguments)
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B("John", 25); 
console.log("age: " + b.age + " name: " + b.name + " random age " + b.random_age);
```

Comment: Ok so basically the apply function actually calls the method A and the arguments passed to apply are forwarded to the argument list of A. I did not know that. I thought apply just copied the whole arguments array to the scope of the A function.

Comment: By the way, do you have a link to another stackoverflow post that shows how to build a generic inheritance function

Comment: Unfortunately I don't :(

Comment: The book uses this one: function inherit(C, P) {

    var F = function () {};

    F.prototype = P.prototype;

    C.prototype = new F();

} which is similar to Doug Crockford's polyfill function.

Answer (score 0):

By executing *A.apply(this, arguments)* from the B function then you are calling A with the two parameters recieved by B. So you must simply ignore the first parameter (name). For that you could do this:

```
function A(age){
  this.age=age;
}
A.prototype.random_age = Math.random();

function B(name,age){
  this.name=name
  Array.prototype.shift.call(arguments); //Here we are deleting the first paramater of B
  A.apply(this, arguments);
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B("John",25); 
console.log("age: " + b.age + " name: " + b.name + " random age " + b.random_age);
```